# Sorting data in MongoDB by insertion time with _id field and allow ties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, pymongo

I want to be able to sort data by insertion time using `_id` field, the thing is it is unique, but, the insertion time isn't (is it?)..

Is it possible to do such sorting ?

What I want to do in short is: If multiple documents have the same insertion time, sort by another field.

I'm using pymongo.

Comment: You can try using `Date` object for this purpose. Also, define the date field with Unique index.

Comment: see how [objectId](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is created, time has precision of second, so its not exactly insertion order.